Can I get a refund for ICE due to cancelled regional bus service?
I booked an ICE (sparpreis ticket) from Oldenburg till Berlin. I could get to Oldenburg Hbf by using a regional bus service (I use the D-ticket), which got canceled. However, the DBahn app did not show that this particular bus service was canceled. I waited at the stop, lost my time and the train. Is there any hope of getting a refund?

What did DB say when you asked them?

What is D-Ticket? Deutschland ticket ?

Did you book the ICE ticket including the trip to get there, or did you just book the ICE trip and organised the bus trip completely on your own?

Shouldn't the bus company compensate you?

"The problem is that the DBahn app did not show that this particular bus service was canceled" > Well, most often than not a bus or train is not cancelled days or hours in advance, but very shortly. You can only get a refund if you book the whole trip. Next time keep that in mind, as it is worth to pay a couple of euros more for a regional service as a small "insurance" to an expensive ICE
.

The combination of Deutschland Ticket (DT) and IC is a borderline case and I haven't seen a specific ruling on this.
Your best shot is probably to just file for compensation and see what happens. Make sure you have your trip start at the beginning of the cancelled bus. This probably depends on whether how this would have played out without the Deutschland Ticket. If you could have bought the entire trip (including the bus) from bahn.de than it's probably inside their jurisdiction. If that would have been two different tickets, than you are most likely out of luck since the delay happened outside the anything that Bahn can control.
I recently did an IC + DT combo. The IC was delayed and as a result I missed the connection to the DT regional train. The delay for the IC portion (which was the only portion ticketed by bahn.de) was less than an hour, but the delay including the DT portion was more than an hour. Bahn paid 25% compensation, so it seems they took the DT part of the trip into account.

There should be something in the Tos of the bus operator or Deutschlandticket or a relevant law or rule. Bus tickets existed prior to the Deutschlandticket and lots of people will have lost their connection due to a bus not showing up.

I have to doubt the last paragraph. The "DT" part of the trip was not part of the ticket with the IC? The problem with such reasoning is that one could always claim "my first leg of the travel, that I took with the Deutschlandticket, was delayed/cancelled" (after all there is almost always one delayed leg reaching the other leg) "and I thus missed the other leg" and likewise for a final leg.

@LoremIpsum: I don't know what to tell you. That is what actually happened. I'm not lying.

You won't get a refund by making a passenger rights claim (which would be the way to go if the regional bus had been a regional train). DB states it here. If you don't trust them, there is also this independent site.
You could of course argue that the wrong information in the app caused you to miss the train, but I'd be very surprised if any legal claim could be derived from that and was not excluded in the terms and conditions of the app.
